# Vscode Giving Errors despite being able to run when I use pygame

Tags: visual-studio-code, pygame

im trying to switch my coding process over to vscode but when i copied some of my old python code it gave me a bunch of errors. I was still able run it fine but it kept saying any line that had "pygame." and then a "()" was an error.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the thing that was breaking my code was that i needed to reload vscode and to reload my python extension

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).